# Are the only 2x2 real matrices with complex-conjugate eigenvalues the rotation matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations, spectral-theory

If so, how can I see this fact?  I'm wondering if it's something fundamental that I am overlooking.

Thanks,

Comment: The matrix $\text{diag}(i,-i)$ would seem to be an obvious counterexample.

Comment: There must be more conditions. The above matrix is orthogonal, but there are lots of matrices with complex eigenvalues that are not orthogonal (or unitary).

Comment: Yes, @copper.hat.  The goal is to reconstruct a real, entrywise nonnegative matrix.  I have already shown that a spectrum consisting of complex eigenvalues is *not* realizable by any real nonnegative matrix in two different ways.  My professor thinks this way, using a rotation matrix argument, is best.  But I didn't follow her reasoning.

Comment: Sorry @Semiclassical, I forgot to mention that the goal is to reconstruct a real matrix, with nonnegative entries.

Comment: Then I'm rather confused what you're asking, given that the above rotation matrix won't have nonnegative entries. More broadly, if the question is missing relevant conditions then it should be edited to include them.

Comment: Oh, @copper.hat, the condition that I am thinking of that is missing from this argument is that:  with the constraints imposed on the matrix (real with nonnegative entries), then the characteristic polynomial has real coefficients, and so the complex eigenvalues given from the prescribed spectrum are conjugates of each other.  So, the spectrum must reduce to the form $\sigma = (\sigma_1, \bar \sigma_1)$.  What do you think now?

Comment: Exactly, @Semiclassical, that's the contradiction that I want to derive.  But first, why use rotation matrices to begin the argument?

Comment: That is not enough.

Comment: What do you mean, @copper.hat?  Thanks,

Comment: The rotation matrix has eigenvalues on the unit circle.

Comment: Hi @Semiclassical, I have edited my question - what do you think now?  Thanks,

Comment: Sure, @copper.hat.  But, what if the spectrum consists of complex-conjugate eigenvalues with modulus bigger than 1?  Why must the realizing matrices of this spectrum be rotation matrices?  Thanks,

Comment: The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ has complex eigenvalues but is not a rotation matrix. Look up the polar decomposition.